# OutputStream not writing mp3 fully

Tags: java, file, mp3, outputstream, fileoutputstream

```
public void getMp4FromYoutube(String httpPath, String absolutePath, String jobName, String email) {
    try {

        byte[] mp3ByteArray = youtubeToMP3(httpPath);
        File mp3File = new File("src/main/resources/audio.mp3");
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mp3File);
        os.write(mp3ByteArray);
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        convertToBase64AndSend(jobName, mp3File, email);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my method, I need it to write an mp3 of a youTube page. For anyone who is worrying, its not to copy videos - I've written a transcription that I want to now download the audio, translate, and delete. When I run this method without continuing the code (though commenting out convertToBase64AndSend) it downloads the whole video audio. However, when I continue to the convertToBase64AndSend method to continue with the translation it only downloads one second of the audio. I'm assuming its something to do with the OutputStream and the way I'm using it? If anybody has any ideas I'd be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling the convertToBase64AndSend method in the getMp4FromYoutube method I called it in the class that had called getMp4FromYouTube. Worked for some reason but I have no idea why! Anybody can give me an explanation I'd be grateful!